# Google api autocomplete predictions with typeahead.js not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, typeahead.js

I want to display typeahead suggestions coming from google autocomplete predictions.

```
 var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();


          $('.delivery_areas').typeahead({
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 3,  

            },{

                name: 'predictions',
                limit: 6,
                async: true,
                source: function(q, sync,async) {
                    matches = [];
                    service.getPlacePredictions({
                        input: q
                    }, function(predictions, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
                                matches.push(prediction.description);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                  //console.log(matches) display a list of suggestions from google
                  async(matches);
                 //cb(matches) also wont work  
                }
            });
```

Somehow it is not working for results coming from autocomplete API.
i have tried both **sync and async** callbacks.

Note : Typeahead is working correctly with example data sources and there is also no problem on the API end. Results are coming and are stored in matches array.

Answer (score 1):

Callback was not at right place

```
$('.delivery_areas').typeahead({
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 3,  

            },{

                name: 'predictions',
                limit: 6,
                async: true,
                source: function(q, sync,async) {
                    matches = [];
                    service.getPlacePredictions({
                        input: q
                    }, function(predictions, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                            predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
                                matches.push(prediction.description);
                            });
                         async(matches);
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```